# Cyclic congruencies

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. Set $x_n := a^n $ modulo $b$. Consider $\{x_n\}$. My question is: is it always true that this sequence must be cyclic?

I am guessing there is some algebraic reason why this is true, but I don't know enough algebra to think of it myself.

Comment: Well, you know there are only finitely many residues modulo $b$...

Comment: perhaps Pigeonhole principle may help you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  Take $a=2, b=4$.  The sequence $a, a^2, a^3, \ldots$ (mod $4$) is $$2, 0, 0,\ldots$$

However, the sequence does have to be *eventually cyclic*.

Comment: I see. And it has to be eventually cyclic because there are only finitely many congruencies modulo $b$, and if say $b_i = b_j$ then we know that $b_{i+1} = b_{j + 1}$ since $b_{i+1} = ab_i$ and similarly $b_{j + 1} = ab_j$. Similarly, $b_{i+2} = b_{j +2}$ and so on, so then you get the recurring sequence.